# Labelled break statement...where next

Tags: java

I'm just doing the Sierra-Bates SCJP study guide and am wondering about the following question:

```
public class Wind {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    foreach:
      for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        for(int k=0; k< 3; k++) {

          System.out.print(" " + j);
          if(j==3 && k==1) break foreach;      //1
          if(j==0 || j==2) break;

        }
      }

  }
}
```

When the value of k is equal to 1 and break foreach is executed (at line 1), where exactly does iteration go after this, to my mind does this now exit the whole loop. Where is the next point of iteration ? How is there any further iterations if the outside loop is exited ?
The answer given in the study book for this is 0111233. The way I see it, only 01 gets printed before the entire loop is exited. No ?

Comment: Did you try executing it? All your question will get solved if you execute it.

Comment: yeah, and 0111233 is what i get. so considering this, after break foreach runs and execution goes back to the start of the outer loop @Santosh, the value of j must remain at 1, is that true, no iteration of the outer loop - as with a continue statement - occurs ? And two more iterations of the inner loop occur while j remains at 1, printing the 11 added to the 01 before the break foreach point ?

Comment: @donoughsugre.. No it is not correct. Your `break foreach` will only be executed once, and then it will break out of your outer loop, thus stopping the iteration. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13311676/1679863), I have posted the complete step by step iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> where exactly does iteration go after this, to my mind does this now
>   exit the whole loop

Yes, since you are breaking out of outer loop. So, it will exit the whole loop you can say.

> Where is the next point of iteration?

There is not iteration after you break out of your outer loop.

> How is there any further iterations if the outside loop is exited ?

No, there will not be any further iteration. Why would you expect any further iteration? When you break out of a loop, then the further iteration of that loop will not run.

For getting the output, try stepping through your code step by step. Take a paper and pencil out, and for each iteraion write the value of `j and k`, and see which `if` is getting executed each time.

Note that, your 2nd if is only breaking out of the inner for loop.

**Here are your two if conditions: -**

```
  if(j==3 && k==1) break foreach;      // 1
  if(j==0 || j==2) break;              // 2
```

**Iterations: -**

1). `j = 0, k = 0`: - Prints 0. First `if` fails, second `if` succeeds. You break out of inner loop. Continue with outer `(j++)`

2). `j = 1, k = 0`: - Prints 1. First `if` fails, second `if` fails. Continue inner loop `(k++)`

3). `j = 1, k = 1`: - Prints 1. Both `if` fails. Continue inner loop `(k++)`

4). `j = 1, k = 2`: - Prints 1. Both `if` fails. Continue inner loop `(k++)`

5). `j = 1, k = 3`: - Inner loop condition fails. Continue outer loop `(j++, k = 0)`

6). `j = 2, k = 0`: - Prints 2. First `if` fails. Second `if` succeeds. Break inner loop. Continue outer loop `(j++)`

7). `j = 3, k = 0`: - Prints 3. Both `if` fails. Continue inner loop. `(k++)`

8). `j = 3, k = 1`: - Prints 3. First `if` succeeds. Breakes out of outer loop. Iteration ends.

Now see, what are the print statements: -

```
0111233
```

Comment: Yes, I think I see it now. Thanks for all your help Rohit.

Comment: Sorry, but just to be certain about it, when the inner loop is broken, no iteration of k occurs ? And the outer loop iterates to the next element ?

Comment: @donoughsugrue.. Yeah. exactly. And then for the next iteration of outer loop, inner loop starts with `k = 0`.

Comment: @donoughsugrue.. You're welcome again. :). Do mark the answer as accepted by clicking the arrow besides it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little easier to see with better printing:

```
public class Temp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    foreach: for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      System.out.println("Outer(j=" + j + ")");
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        System.out.println("Inner (j=" + j + "; k=" + k +")" );
        if (j == 3 && k == 1) break foreach; // 1
        if (j == 0 || j == 2) break;
      }
      System.out.println("Outer - after inner loop");
    }
    System.out.println("Not in a loop");
  }
}
```

The general rule is that a break statement moves execution to the first statement outside the loop which follows it.  That can be a little confusing when the loop is itself the last statement in another loop's body, because the statement following the inner loop is the loop mechanism of the outer loop (i.e. the test of a while loop or the action-and-test of a for loop)

The unqualified break statement exits the inner loop and then finishes the current iteration of the outer loop (where it says "after inner loop").

The qualified break statement exits the outer loop and goes to the first statement following the outer for loop.

This results in the following output.

```
Outer(j=0)
Inner (j=0; k=0)
Outer - after inner loop
Outer(j=1)
Inner (j=1; k=0)
Inner (j=1; k=1)
Inner (j=1; k=2)
Outer - after inner loop
Outer(j=2)
Inner (j=2; k=0)
Outer - after inner loop
Outer(j=3)
Inner (j=3; k=0)
Inner (j=3; k=1)
not in a loop
```

Comment: Yeah, this and Rohit's answer makes much more sense than my one...thanks Mel.